# Heroku: how to detect if foreman is running

Tags: django, heroku, foreman

I am using eclipse to develop my Django project, and it will be deployed to Heroku. In order to detect if the app is running on Heroku, the `settings.py` is modified:

```
if 'DYNO' in os.environ:    # Is running on Heroku
    DEBUG = False
else:
    DEBUG = True
...

if DEBUG==True:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            ... 
        }
    }
else:    # For Heroku
    # Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {'default':dj_database_url.config()}
    # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Also modify `wsgi.py`:

```
from <myApp> import settings

if settings.DEBUG==True:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
else:    # For Heroku
    from dj_static import Cling
    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

The above modifications are to identify if the app is running locally with `runserver` or on Heroku. However, if I try to run `foreman start` instead of `runserver`, the settings in `wsgi.py` will not work since `foreman` also requires `Cling`.

Is there a way that I can detect if the app is run by `foreman` so that I can make proper setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku provide you `DATABASE_URL`, So If '`DATABASE_URL`' does no exist, then it's local machine

```
if not os.environ.has_key('DATABASE_URL'):
        os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://user:password@localhost/name'

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])}
```

**Updated :** Match answer to the exact question.

*Procfile*

```
export SERVER_ENV=foreman
web: gunicorn yourapp.wsgi
```

*wsgi.py*

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_ENV') == 'foreman':
    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
else:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to identify if the app is running locally or on Heroku. I am trying to identify if the app is running locally with `manage.py runserver` or with `foreman start`.

Comment: @yltang52 Sorry for late replay, i was travelling. And i updated my answer.